# Unity3D: Error with my code

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, error-handling

I'm getting an error on a code of mine, and was wondering if anyone can help me with this, I search up the problem and tried out the soultion but nothing seemed to work. (what I tried/searched up: move my c# script linked up to the script below in the standard assets folder) Thank you!

This is the error I am getting:

The name 'GameManager' does not denote a valid type ('not found')

And this is the code

**EDIT**

```
 var thisMaterial : Material;

 private var gameManager : GameManager;
 private var moveDirection : Vector2;
 private var movePosition : Vector2;
 private var lastDirection : int;

  function Start()
{
   gameManager = (GameManager)FindObjectOfType(typeof(GameManager));
    thisMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Transparent"));
    GetComponent("MeshRenderer").material = thisMaterial;
    thisMaterial.mainTexture = gameManager.game.characters[0].spriteSheet;
    thisMaterial.mainTextureOffset = gameManager.animationList[0][0];
    movePosition = gameManager.game.startPosition;
 }

   function Update()
 {
    var vectorMovePosition : Vector3 = Vector3(movePosition.x, movePosition.y, transform.position.z);
    var distanceToVector : float = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, vectorMovePosition);
    var inputDirection : Vector2 = Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized;
    if(inputDirection != Vector2.zero && distanceToVector < 0.1)
    {
        if(inputDirection == -Vector2.up) lastDirection = 0;
        else if(inputDirection == -Vector2.right) lastDirection = 1;
        else if(inputDirection == Vector2.right) lastDirection = 2;
        else if(inputDirection == Vector2.up) lastDirection = 3;
        else return;

         thisMaterial.mainTextureOffset = gameManager.animationList[lastDirection][0];
        if(gameManager.game.scenes[gameManager.currentScene].GetTile(3, movePosition + inputDirection) == Vector2(-1, -1))
        {
            moveDirection = inputDirection;
            movePosition = vectorMovePosition + moveDirection;
        }
    }
    if(transform.position != vectorMovePosition)
    {
        thisMaterial.mainTextureOffset = gameManager.animationList[lastDirection][Mathf.Round(distanceToVector * 3)];
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, vectorMovePosition, Time.deltaTime * 3);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is your problem.

```
gameManager = FindObjectOfType(GameManager);
```

This should be like this:

```
gameManager = (GameManager)FindObjectOfType(typeof(GameManager));
```

Alternatives:

If that gameobject is not the same as the one that the above script is on:

```
gameManager = GameObject.FindWithTag("SomeTag").GetComponent<GameManager>();
```

If it is on the same gameobject, this will do:

```
gameManager = GetComponent<GameManager>();
```

Or using the inspector to assign the variable.

Of course, if all of that doesn't work, you don't actually have `GameManager` script attached to something.

Comment: Thank you for replying back to me, however I an now getting another error: UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end.

Comment: I tried out this one you suggested:  gameManager = (GameManager)FindObjectOfType(typeof(GameManager)); . But still getting an error

Comment: That missing `;` is an syntax error. I can't tell what the error is without seeing the code with that.

Comment: I can't tell because I don't know your current code.

Comment: I have update my code if you can please look at the edit above, it's not much just as you suggested. Thank you for replying

Comment: I think the `new` in `thisMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Transparent"));` is not meant to be there in jvascript.

Comment: No sorry, I don't think that's it cause I tried it out but I'm still get the same error. Thank you though for the suggestion. Do you have anymore cause I'm completely stumped

Comment: Ok, I see that my above suggestion for `FindObjectOfType` is `C#`, the javascript syntax is different. That actually is `gameManager = FindObjectOfType(GameManager);` like you had it. Are you having only javascript classes or are you using some C# too? (GameManager in that case.) And that other script is called exactly `GameManager`?

Comment: Yes I do have other c# script too. However it's not called exactly GameManager, however I did change the c# script name to match my javascript class but it's still not working.

Comment: If you want to call a C# function javascript you need to watch out for the compilation order. Have a look for `unity javascript call c#`. That should get you information about how to setup stuff.